# Partial view table drag and drop rows in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Is it possible to drag and drop a table row from one partial view to another partial view in asp.net core MVC using HTML 5, Web API and jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean drag and drop rows ?

Comment: I have used two partial view parent and child, their parent and child record displayed in that two partial view. Now I need to drag child table(grid) row into parent for make parent change